# NodeJS - Get unique devicefingerprint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, docker

I have a node/express App and i would like to get the unique device fingerprint from where the app gets invoked. I came across some of the famous fingerprinting open source packages like https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2 but unfortunately this library supports browser fingerprinting and not generate unique fingerprint for every single device from where the app gets invoked (https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2/issues/80#issuecomment-148302793)

I also tried the device methods in clientjs https://clientjs.org/#Device-getDevice but was returning undefined (https://github.com/jackspirou/clientjs/issues/65) and this again is a client side library.

What i'm trying to accomplish is to get the unique device fingerprint on the server side. Like say for example consider a scenario where the app is invoked from 2 devices with the exact same configuration (like type, vendor and model) and in this use case i should be getting 2 unique device fingerprints.

The getDevice() in https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js seems to be pretty close to what i'm looking for but not sure if it would satisfy my above use case, i.e. 2 devices with the exact same config (for example 2 iPhone 6) and i'm wondering in that case the type and vendor would be the same but not sure about the model value. Any idea or thoughts please share.

Also Augur (https://www.augur.io/) is the most recommended device recognition software, but unfortunately it's no more an open source

Answer (score 4):

**express-fingerprint** provides a fingerprinting system based on characteristics observable in the contents of Web requests, without the use of any code executing on the client side.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fingerprint

Comment: express-fingerprint generates a different hash every time the call is made from the same client or device.

Answer (score 0):

If you run on nestjs, using
[nestjs-fingerprint](https://github.com/l1ttps/nestjs-fingerprint)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).